# Android: conerting Image into byteArray

Tags: android, image, bitmap, arrays

In my project I have an bitmap image. I need to convert this picture to byteArray in order to manipulate some bytes and after that save it as image.

with this code `image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.tasnim);` I have acces to width and height but how can I have access to bytes of this image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the OP wants to manipulate the pixels, not the header information of the Image...

Assuming your `image` is a `Bitmap`

```
int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
int[] rgbStream = new int[w * h];
image.getPixels(rgbStream, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
```

Of course, this gets you Pixel values as Integers...But you can always convert them again.

```
    int t = w * h;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        pixel = rgbStream[i];  //get pixel value (ARGB)
        int A = (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF; //Isolate Alpha value...
        int R = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF; //Isolate Red Channel value...
        int G = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF; //Isolate Green Channel value...
        int B = pixel & 0xFF; //Isolate Blue Channel value...
                       //NOTE, A,R,G,B can be cast as bytes...


    }
```

Comment: Thanks cool st0le, but i have a question. I think in bitmap images, each pixel includes 3 bytes for R,G and B. So, shall I write int[w * h * 3] instead of int[w * h] in second line?

Comment: oh, i think each integer includes 4 bytes so doesn't need to * 3. correct?

Comment: no, see the pixel values are stored entirely in a single integer...so ARGB (each of 1 byte x4) is stored as an integer `(4 bytes)`....so each integer is an entire pixel not just A,R,G,B...you'll need bitwise operations to extract/isolate them. :) i'll add an edit just in case, to help you out...

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Most correct way is:

```
ByteBuffer copyToBuffer(Bitmap bitmap){
    int size = bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getRowBytes();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size); gives OutOfMemoryException. Any ideas!!